# Handling response object from Each promise in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, es6-promise

I have an post end point which creates customers and returns userId as response

For example

```js
// Post Data
const customers = [{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    userId: '12345
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Phil',
    lastName: 'Doe',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Dan',
    lastName: 'Joe',
  }
]


app.post('/customers', (req, res) => {
  const arrayPromises = []
  const customers = req.body.customers;
  customers.forEach((customer) => {
    //checking whether I have a userId already
    if (!customer.userId) {
      const postRequest = {
        headers: Object.assign(res._headers, {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        post:'www.createUserExample.com,
        customer // post data,
      };
      arrayPromises.push(axios(postRequest))
      //response will be {userId}
    }
  })


  Promise.all(arrayPromises).then(result => {
    //by this way I get all userids
    res.status(200).json(result.data)
  })


})
```

But I need to send a response object back with including userIds

sample response object should be like

```js
[{
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith',
    userId: '12345'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Phil',
    lastName: 'Doe',
    userId: '65765'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Dan',
    lastName: 'Joe',
    userId: '786876'
  }
]
```

So over all I would like to have properties of customers and append the created userId to post data object and send as a response.

Plase let me know the best way to do. I like to do asynchronous reqs to create customers

Comment: please fix the code inside of `if (!customer.userId) { ... }` this is not valid as it is right now

Comment: I have fixed my typo for post end point

Comment: Is the service just sending the userId back? or the entire user obj?

Comment: sending only the userId back

Comment: `result` is an **array** of `{userId}` objects, it doesn't have a `.data` property?

Comment: I can access array of {userId} from result.data

Answer (score 1):

Just push the objects that already have an id to the array. (Or promises for them). `Promise.all` will then result in the array that you are looking for. The array doesn't necessarily need to contain only promises for the API requests:

```
const arrayPromises = []
const customers = req.body.customers;
customers.forEach((customer) => {
  //checking whether I have a userId already
  if (customer.userId) {
    arrayPromises.push(Promise.resolve(customer));
  } else {
    arrayPromises.push(axios(…));
  }
});
```

You can also simplify to

```
const arrayPromises = req.body.customers.map((customer) => {
  //checking whether I have a userId already
  return customer.userId
    ? Promise.resolve(customer)
    : axios(…);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to filter for users without IDs:

```
const idLess = customers.filter(customer => !customer.userId);
```

Then you make your requests for `idLess` instead of `customers`.

```
const arrayPromises = idLess.map(customer => {
    const postRequest = {
        headers: Object.assign(res._headers, {
           Accept: 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        post:'www.createUserExample.com,
        customer // post data,
    };

    // if your service responds with the entire obj:
    return axios(postRequest);

    // if your service responds just with ids:
    return axios(postRequest).then(id => Object.assign({
       userId: id
    }, customer))l
});
```

Now you need to filter for users **with** IDs:

```
const idd = customers.filter(customer => customer.userId);
```

Then you join your arrays.

```
Promise.all(arrayPromises).then(result => {
   // either with concat
   res.status(200).json(result.data.concat(idd));

   // or by destructuring
   res.status(200).json([...result.data, ...idd]);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the `customers`, returning the ones that already have a `userId` and making post requests for those that do not.

```
const promises = customers.map(async (customer) => {
    //checking whether I have a userId already
    if (customer.userId) {
        return customer;
    }

    const {userId} = await axios({
        headers: Object.assign(res._headers, {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        post: 'www.createUserExample.com',
        customer // post data,
    });
    return {userId, ...customer};
});
```